# Arduino readString can't follow a command

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I have a problem with my code, yesterday it woked fine for me but when I changed a single thing it didn't work, CTRL-Z and the previous code also didn't work anymore.

```
String readString = "";
int Rand = 0;
String Random = "";
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    while(!Serial.available());

    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    delay(3);
    char c = Serial.read();
    readString += c; 
    }
    Serial.print(readString);
    if(readString == "Hi"){
      Rand = random(5100,9999);
      String Random = String(((((Rand - 5) * 2) - 36) / 2 - 3) * 2);
      Serial.print(Random);
    }
    readString = "";
}
```

This is my code, the thing that doesn't work for me is that whenever I put a command in the serial port, it gets shown by the Serial.print(readString); but if I type "Hi" (without quotationmarks), the if(readString == "Hi") seems to not work.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it that the if statement recognises the Hi I send it?

Comment: I am confuse  if(readString == "Hi")  is not working right ? what is the output of Serial.print(readString);?

Comment: yeah put some of your console logs too..

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine told the answer. He said that if you have a string there will be a new line caracter in it, the way is that tou have to trim the variable before the if-statement, do readString.trim();.

Answer (score 0):

I've sended similar error like you. You can try this;

```
if (stringOne.equals(stringTwo)) { //to do
```

stringOne is "Hi" and strintTwo is readString.

I hope to solve this solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

"readString" is the name of a built-in function of the Serial (inherited to SerialX). This may cause a clash.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35172102)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).